# configure Ivy 2.2.0 through build.xml instead of installing it on machine

Tags: ivy

I want to use ivy 2.2.0 jar instead of installing ivy on my machine because when anyone import my project from svn its giving errors for jars which I have added to Ivy library.

I added ivy.xml to build path through option add ivy library. how I can configure it through build.xml instead of add ivy library option..

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Ivy without the ivy.jar file? This is not possible.

However, you can make it easier for your users. Ant can automatically download Ivy for you the first time it is used. For the following times, just add Ivy itself as a dependency of your project, so you can easily roll out updates of Ivy, for example.

For the bootstrapping (getting Ivy with plain Ant) see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855381/396730) to another SO question.