# objectify4 build breaking

Tags: ant, objectify

Hi I cloned the repo using `git clone https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/`
When I run `ant jar` I get the following error -

```
D:\gae\objectify4\objectify-appengine\build.xml:76: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:cachepath
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration.
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -E:\Softwares\apache-ant-1.8.4\lib
        -C:\Users\shwetanka\.ant\lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

Need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:  Ignore this answer, the build is now Gradle-based.  Install Gradle and run "gradle build".  The wiki has been updated:  https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/ContributingToObjectify

---

Wow, quick timing!  I switched the build to Ivy yesterday, but haven't updated the docs yet.

Download Ivy and copy the ivy jar to ~/.ant/lib.  Then you should be able to build.  There are no other config requirements (the edit-this-to-build.properties has been deleted).

If you want to work with Objectify in Eclipse, download IvyIDE.

There will be more changes to the build system in the next couple days as I figure out how to get Ivy to sign and publish artifacts to Maven Central.

BTW: For a faster response, post to the Objectify Google Group.

Comment: See this answer for a method of bootstrapping your build to use ivy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853851/ivy-fails-to-resolve-a-dependancy-unable-to-find-cause/9855381#9855381