# Spring-Tool-Suite (STS) cannot find ivy.jar while it is installed in ~/.ant/lib, and command line build succeed

Tags: ant, ivy

I cloned a new repo which has a build.xml, which begins with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="mbark" basedir=".." xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
```

But this line when I run in STS,

```
<target name="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
    <ivy:retrieve type="jar"/>
```

always failed in a message like this:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/myusername/Documents/workspace-sts-3.2.0.RELEASE/mbark/conf/build.xml:26: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:retrieve
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -/home/myusername/springsource/sts-3.2.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/lib
        -/home/myusername/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

I can browse to my ant home folder and locate the ivy.jar; I can build from the command line; I also specified ANT_HOME in the project | properties | Resource | Linked Resources | Path Variables (though I dont think this setting will help, I did that), but the running ant inside STS still complains.

Could any ant/ivy expert give some clue?

Answer (score 1):

From your STS Window,  Go to "Windows"-> "Preferences" and make sure all ant jar files are listed there and make sure the path to those ant jars are correct.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and put the ivy jar in one of the following locations listed in the error message?

> Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
>
> ```
>     -/home/myusername/springsource/sts-3.2.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/lib
>     -/home/myusername/.ant/lib
> ```

Your problem is that Eclipse has it's own mechanism for managing ANT. It will ignore the ANT_HOME environment variable.

For more details (and a possible work-around) see the following answer:

- [Ivy fails to resolve a dependency, unable to find cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853851/ivy-fails-to-resolve-a-dependancy-unable-to-find-cause/9855381#9855381)

Comment: I did have ivy.jar installed. The command line build using ant and build.xml works perfectly.