# Liferay Portal build error: Failed to create task antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:settings

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, liferay

I'm new to Liferay Portal. My configuration is:

- apache-ant-1.8.0-bin
- liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6
- liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-ce-ga1-20160331161017956
- liferay-ide-eclipse-updatesite-1.6.2

I am learning how to build the service, using the service builder in Liferay. While doing so, I'm receiving the following error:

```
[Console output redirected to
file:D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.eclipse.sdk\sdk.log]
Buildfile:
D:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-ce-ga1-20160331161017956\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\portlets\guestbook-portlet\build.xml
[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource
org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED
D:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-ce-ga1-20160331161017956\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\portlets\guestbook-portlet\build.xml:5:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-ce-ga1-20160331161017956\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\portlets\build-common-portlet.xml:5:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-ce-ga1-20160331161017956\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\build-common-plugin.xml:5:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-ce-ga1-20160331161017956\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\build-common.xml:57: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-ce-ga1-20160331161017956\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\build-common-ivy.xml:719:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-ce-ga1-20160331161017956\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\build-common-ivy.xml:166:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-ce-ga1-20160331161017956\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0\build-common-ivy.xml:193:
Problem: failed to create task or type
antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:settings Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling. Action: Check that any custom tasks/types
have been declared. Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef>
declarations have taken place. No types or tasks have been defined in
this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration.  Action: Check that the
implementing library exists in one of:
        -D:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730\lib
        -C:\Users\33329\.ant\lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

When checked, it's failing at the following taskdef in build-common-ivy.xml:

```
<taskdef classpathref="ivy.lib.path" resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" />
```

Please advise on how to solve this problem.

Comment: check this [Ivy fails to resolve a dependency, unable to find cause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853851/ivy-fails-to-resolve-a-dependency-unable-to-find-cause)

Comment: :) write your solution so others don't struggle to much :P